# Overwrite resource file with maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, resources, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, overwrite

I use maven-assembly-plugin with "jar-with-dependencies" to package jar. There are 2 dependencies artifact having log-back.xml. The second artifact is depend on the first one. I want to have log-back.xml of the second artifact in final jar, but it always contain log-back.xml of the first one. So how can I control this?

Thanks

Comment: Here is an answer for one particular case http://stackoverflow.com/a/24578209/1531945 In general, manipulating `dependencySets` and `unpackOptions` should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [unpackOptions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/component.html#class_unpackOptions) to achieve this.  Try something like the following:

```
<assembly>
...
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>${groupId}:${artifact.whose.logback.is.to.be.excluded} </include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/logback.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>${groupId}:${artifact.whose.logback.is.to.be.excluded}</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: I got your idea but It does not work. logback.xml is not included in final jar. Perhaps, the plugin expanded the jars, then package them with the filter (exclude logback.xml)

Comment: This works for me only in the first build after I edit assembly.xml. If I run the build again, it stops working. Seems the order in which resources are copied is undefined, and therefore there is no guarantee this will work.

Answer (score 3):

(With last version of maven-assembly-plugin at this time : 3.0.0)

I had the same problem with an assembly build.

I had tow dependencies with the same properties file but with a different content (one good and the other overwritting the first with missing declarations).

The problem was that i finally had the bad configuration file replacing the other in my assembly jar.

The only cleanest solution i found to overwrite the file was to :

1 - Add the good file that i wanted to keep for the build in my project :
ex: `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/myfileWhichOverwriteTheBadDependenciesRessources.xml`

2 - Add a fileset with 'filtered' setted to 'true' in my assembly descriptor :

```
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.main.resources}/META-INF</directory>
        <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
        <filtered>true</filtered>
    </fileSet>
```

(the 'project.main.resource' property is setted to 'src/main/resources' in my case)

Comment: You could use backticks ` to mark things as `code` in your answer, so e.g. the file name would be more readable then.

Answer (score 1):

Is the first artifact a module of your own project? If so, you could exclude the log-back.xml there in the resources section of the pom.xml.

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>log-back.xml</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
  ...
</resources>
```

However, this only works if this module does not require the log-back.xml by itself when it is built out of the scope of the overall jar.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the first artifact.

Comment: Oh, ok, then I think this is going to be difficult.
As far as a I know you can only exclude transitive dependencies of dependencies, but not contents that are bundled within a dependency.