# Maven jar file editing

Tags: xml, maven, jar

At the moment for a project I'm working on I'm using a Maven style project.

I'm using Maven for all my dependencies.

One of my dependencies is a `jar` file ([ExtentReports](https://github.com/anshooarora/extentreports)).

I want to edit an XML file within this `jar` file. How can I achieve this?

I've seen online about using a ZIP tool, but would it not be overwritten once the program is re-run as I'm using Maven? Or is my concept of Maven wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
  <configuration>
    <!-- report theme -->
    <!-- standard, dark -->
    <theme>standard</theme>
```

I want to change the above to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
  <configuration>
    <!-- report theme -->
    <!-- standard, dark -->
    <theme>dark</theme>
```

Comment: you want to edit an XML file of one of your dependencies, why? you can unpack the dependency and have the XML file placed somewhere in your project, then work on it as a copy, would that suit your requirements?

Comment: I presume it might? Would you have any articles to show how this can be achieved? Thanks @A.DiMatteo

Comment: to be more clear, do you need this edited XML for some logic or you need to override the library's one with your edited one? Does at runtime this library need to read the edit and ignore its own copy?

Comment: Theres a line in the XML that I need to change. I don't have an edited version I just want to edit the one thats already there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven overwrite resource file in dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085996/maven-overwrite-resource-file-in-dependency)

Comment: BTW, did you add this depencency `jar` to your Maven repo(s)? If not see [maven-install-plugin:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) and [maven-deploy-plugin:deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).

Comment: No Not install-file etc. use build-helper-maven-plugin to attach the appropriate file.

Comment: I edited the question to maybe give a clearer insight to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct approach as the settings part of the ExtentReports.jar are default and any other settings that you load during runtime overwrite default ones.

See here:  http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/java/#configuration

Copy the entire configuration block from the above link, place it inside an XML file and put it in your source.  After that, simply use one of the methods below to load the XML when your project starts:

```
// file location: "C:\HelloWorld\extent-config.xml"
loadConfig(new File("C:\HelloWorld\extent-config.xml"));


// loadConfig(Class clazz, String fileName);
// clazz: com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports
// packagePath of clazz: com/relevantcodes/extentreports
// final path: com/relevantcodes/extentreports/extent-config.xml
loadConfig(ExtentReports.class, "extent-config.xml");


// loadConfig(Class clazz, String basePackagePath, String fileName;
// clazz: com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports
//  packagePath of clazz: com/relevantcodes/extentreports
// basePackagePath: "resources"
// final path: com/relevantcodes/extentreports/resources/extent-config.xml
loadConfig(ExtentReports.class, "resources", "extent-config.xml");
```

Comment: Hey @Anshoo . This sounds good ! More what I was thinking about. Ill give it a go ! Much appreciated .

Comment: Also Anshoo, can this be used for any file in the JAR or just the configuration file?

Comment: This is as per design, only for config.xml.