# Maven building jar: merge duplicate resources from dependencies

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm getting this problem:

I have a project with spring-boot. It works perfectly on eclipse, but I need to generate a jar with dependencies, so I add the maven-assembly-plugin configuration to the pom.

Some spring dependencies has in the META-INF a file called spring.schemas, and I need to merge all spring.schemas into one (spring-context, spring-beans, etc)

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598314/merge-properties-files-with-maven-assembly) using maven-shade-pluggin and AppendingTransformer, and it merges all spring.schemas perfectly... But it has an issue, when I execute the jar, it fails with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'lib/spring-boot-starter-batch-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar'. 
It has been compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression.
Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
```

So, shade plugin compress the jar, and spring-boot doesn't like it, and there's no way to turn off the compression in shade. I manually copy the shade spring.schemas generated by shade and I put it in the maven-assembly-pluggin generated and uncompressed jar with dependencies. It works.

Then I tried to include the generated spring.schemas into my resources folder, but it's allways overrided by the spring.schemas from spring-context.

I also tried [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027519/overwrite-resource-file-with-maven-assembly-plugin) to exclude spring.schemas from dependency jar using a descriptor XML in assembly, but it doesn't work:

```xtml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>org.springframework:spring-context</include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/spring.schemas</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-context</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
        </dependencySet> 
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

```xml
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <compress>false</compress>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This are my dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySql 5.5 Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using maven-assembly-plugin and maven-shade-pluggin, I would try to use Spring Boot's own spring-boot-maven-plugin that can be used to create an executable ‘fat’ JAR. See [this reference documentation page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html), section "73.2 Create an executable JAR with Maven".

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Or, if you don't use the spring-boot-starter-parent POM:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maven-assembly-plugin`.

Add the plugin to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <descriptors>
      <descriptor>fat-jar.xml</descriptor>
    </descriptors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Add a `fat-jar.xml` descriptor next to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd">
  <id>fat</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <containerDescriptorHandlers>
    <containerDescriptorHandler>
      <handlerName>metaInf-spring</handlerName>
    </containerDescriptorHandler>
  </containerDescriptorHandlers>
</assembly>
```

Notice the `metaInf-spring` handler. It will merge any META-INF duplicate files having names starting with the `spring` word.

The reference documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-container-descriptor-handlers.html